# ASP.NET UrlRewriter - How to Write RegEx for Root?

Tags: asp.net, regex, url-rewriting, urlrewriter.net, urlrewriter

I have been trying to use UrlRewriter (Intelligencia.UrlRewriter.dll) in a test project.

My rewrite statement is as in the following:

```
<rewrite url="~/Sample/(.+)" to="~/Sample.aspx?Test=$1"/>
```

This statement works great for a URL like:

```
http://localhost:4188/RewriteTest/Sample/12345
```

or, let's say:

```
http://RewriteTest.com/Sample/12345
```

And, I can retrieve the value "12345" in Sample.aspx file as:

```
Label1.Text = "Test: " + Request.QueryString["Test"];
```

And when I hit the root link, it successfully displays the Default.aspx:

`http://localhost:4188/RewriteTest/`   or   `http://RewriteTest.com/`

What I want to accomplish is taking the "Sample" off the regex statement, so that I can directly hit  `http://RewriteTest.com/12345`  and  display Sample.aspx by retrieving "12345" value. And, when the root is hit  `http://RewriteTest.com/`  it will simply display Default.aspx as it is now.

Is it possible? Can the regex statement be updated to something else for this purpose?

Thank you,

Niyazi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your ID code is always going to be 5 digit number then you could have clamped the regex to that:

```
<rewrite url="^~/([\d]{5})$" to="~/Sample.aspx?Test=$1"/>
```

Or a variable length number:

```
<rewrite url="^~/([\d]+)$" to="~/Sample.aspx?Test=$1"/>
```